# Two different fonts for math and text

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mathspec

I tried to prepare slides in Linux Biolinum O, but I do not like the maths fonts, and I wanted to use TeX Gyre Pagella, for the maths environments. I tried the following source, which obviously doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Rochester}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\usefonttheme{serif}

%--- Fonts
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin){TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum O}

%--- Language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[variant=uk]{english}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Starter}

Bla bla bla

\[
\sin x + \cos x = abc
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Can you tell me what how I can have a Palatino-like font for maths, with Linux Biolinum O text?

Cheers

Andrea

Comment: Use `unicode-math` instead of `mathspec`; the aim of the latter is to have *the same* font for math and text.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. However, even if I use [unicode-math] instead, the x's are in Linux Biolinum O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `unicode-math` rather than `mathspec`; you also need the `professionalfonts` theme.

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usetheme{Rochester}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\usefonttheme{serif,professionalfonts}

\setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\setmainlanguage[variant=uk]{english}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Starter}

Bla bla bla

\[
\sin x + \cos x = abc
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want “sin” and “cos” in Pagella, add also

```
\setmathrm{TeX Gyre Pagella}
```

after the `\setmathfont` line.

[image]